# Get all characters after first hyphen in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, csv

I have a messy CSV file that looks like this:

```
Name,Job Title,Employee Type
Bob Smith,3F03029G-IT Technician - Help Desk,Regular
```

I want to use PowerShell to clean up the "Job Title" field. In the past, I could use a split:

```
$title = $_."Job Title"
$cleanTitle = $title.split('-')[-1]
```

But for the above example, it would ignore everything after the second hyphen:

```
IT Technician
```

Instead of what I want:

```
IT Technician - Help Desk
```

Any thoughts on how I can grab everything after the first hyphen in the column instead of just grabbing what is in between the first and second hyphens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly the lowest computing overhead:

```
$title.Substring($title.IndexOf('-') + 1)
```

Possibly closest to your existing code, limit the split to 2 pieces, take the last one:

```
$title.Split('-', 2)[-1]
```

Comment: I chose to try the one closest to my existing code. Can you explain why it works even with multiple hyphens? For example... if the job title is "3F03029G-IT Tech - Help Desk - I" shouldn't it drop the IT Tech?

Comment: It shouldn't drop text you want, or it would be a rubbish answer :-P [Split(separator, count) method overload documentation is here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1bs0eda(v=vs.110).aspx); relevant bits are "*count - max num of substrings to return. [..] If there are more than count substrings, the first count-1 are returned in the first count-1 elements, and remaining characters are returned in the last element*", i.e. after the 1st hyphen the title is split into 2 parts, that is the count limit of 2 in the method call, everything after that hyphen stays together as one string.

Comment: Appreciate the explanation @TessellatingHecker. Marking this as the answer since it most directly answered the question. The regex did the trick and was a unique way to solve the problem but the split was closest to what I was looking for. Thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex to replace the beginning

```
'3F03029G-IT Technician - Help Desk' -replace '^.*?-'
```

The regex just captures everything up to and including the first dash and replaces it with nothing

Comment: This worked like a champ. I used $cleanTitle = $title -replace '^.*?-' as you suggested and it returned expected clean results. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use -split with 3 arguments. 3th argument give max number split

Like this :

```
$stringtest="3F03029G-IT Technician - Help Desk"
($stringtest -split '-', 2)[1]
```